# Android - Service - On Start Command Called only once

Tags: android, android-service

In my activity oncreate method, i have called a service using OnStartCommand(). My requirement is when the user is on the same Activity (when the Activity is visible), a set of code should run repeatedly. (Example .. I should make a web service call and get the response and do some action based on it after regular intervals).

I have put this set of code in this method.

```
@Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent i, int flags , int startId){

        // Code to be repeated

return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

But, this is getting executed only once. How to make it run repeatedly from the time the user came to this page till he leaves this page ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CountDownTimer.cancel() method seems to be not working.

I would recommend you to use Timer instead. It's much more flexible and can be cancelled at any time. It may be something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    TextView mTextField;
    long elapsed;
    final static long INTERVAL=1000;
    final static long TIMEOUT=5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mTextField=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        TimerTask task=new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                elapsed+=INTERVAL;
                if(elapsed>=TIMEOUT){
                    this.cancel();
                    displayText("finished");
                    return;
                }
                //if(some other conditions)
                //   this.cancel();
                displayText("seconds elapsed: " + elapsed / 1000);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer();
       timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, INTERVAL, INTERVAL);
   }

    private void displayText(final String text){
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTextField.setText(text);
            }});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer for the fixed-period execution of a method.

See here is a tutorial on this:

http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12

Comment: Use CountDownTimer

 CountDownTimer t = new CountDownTimer( Long.MAX_VALUE , 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("test","Timer tick");
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d("test","Timer last tick");            
            t.start();
        }
     }.start();

Comment: Since i need to make a web service call in the background when the user is viewing this activity, will i get any memory issue or force close?